# How to replace some string with capturing group in Python 3?

Tags: python, regex

I'm a Python beginner.
I'd like to find <(.+?)> from a string, and replace it with [\1].
For example,

```
string_input = '<age>'
string_output = '[age]'
```

I tried,

```
import re
string = '<age>'
re.sub('<.+?>, '[' + \1 + ']', string)
```

But it failed.

Comment: use \g<> is recommended as it can avoid ambiguity like '\12\3'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> re.sub('<(.+)>', '[\\1]', '<age>')
'[age]'
```

Double `\\` is used to escaping the `\`, or else `\1` will be recognised as `\x01`.
Brackets `()` are used as a capturing group.

You can use multiple capturing groups like this:

```
>>> re.sub('<(.+)=+(.*)>', '[\\1: \\2]', '<age=5>')
'[age: 5]'
```

Answer (score 1):

You best access the capturing group by using `\g<>`, so since you only have one capturing group, you use `\g<1>`.

```
In [1]: re.sub(r'<(.+?)>', '[\g<1>]', '<age>')
Out[1]: '[age]'
```

The advantage of using `\g<>` is that you can also give names to your capturing groups and then access them by the names again, for example:

```
In [2]: re.sub(r'<(?P<content>.+?)>', '[\g<content>]', '<age>')
Out[2]: '[age]'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
re.sub("<([^>]+)>", "[\g<1>]", s)
```

Answer (score 0):

As Alex L says, but you don't need the ? character:

```
import re
re.sub('<(.+)>', '[\\1]', '<age>')
```